# Chinese Historical Tick Data

Tags: china

Does anyone know where I can find and purchase Chinese historical tick data?  Seems like so hard to find out there.

Answer (score 1):

Tushare has some available both tick and price bars

Comment: This one ? https://pypi.org/project/tushare/

Comment: That's the one:
https://tushare.pro/